# Could not import PIL.Image

Tags: python

When I'd like to use `train_generator.next()` method for doing deep learning project, I found the mistake information:

```
'Could not import `PIL.Image`. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.'
```

But I have already written the code 
import PIL
from PIL import Image
X,y=train_generator.next()

How could I fix this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have `PIL` installed?

Answer (score 0):

Instal PIL via pip or via system package manager (in some cases pip's PIL doesn't work)

PIP:
`pip install Pillow`

Ubuntu (apt):
`sudo apt-get install python-PIL`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pillow using:

```
pip install Pillow
```

And the use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Hope this helps.